# Python - Is there a way to prevent my list class from changing?

Tags: python, list, class, oop

I have a class called `Maps` from which I created two list `l` and `lm`. `l` is supposed to change with a certain events but `lm` (memory list) is supposed to stay as is.

Is there a way to prevent my list class from changing?
Tnak you!

```
class Maps(list):

    def createInitial(self, lvlC):
        #self.extend(mapDico[lvlC.value])

    #get (i,j) coords of "i" in l
    def findI(self):
        for ordinate, abscissa in enumerate(self):
            try:
                return (ordinate, abscissa.index("i"))
            except:
                pass

    #get number of "x" in lm
    def countX(self):
        nbX=0
        for rows in range(len(self)):
            for elements in range(len(self)):
                if self[rows][elements]=="x":
                    nbX+=1
        return nbX

    #load next map
    def nextLevel(self, nxtL):
        del self[:]
        self.extend(mapDico[nxtL])

lvlC=Counters()
lm=Maps()
lm.createInitial(lvlC)
l=Maps()
l.createInitial(lvlC)
```

Here starts the "controller" file:

```
             if goalC.value>0 and goalC.value==lm.countX():
            lvlC.increment(1)
            #lvl.config(text=" | Level Complete ", bg="limegreen")
            l.nextLevel(lvlC.value)
            lm.nextLevel(lvlC.value)
            muvC.reinitialize()
            nbMuv.config(text="Moves: "+str(muvC.value))
            pushC.reinitialize()
            nbPush.config(text=" | Pushes: "+str(pushC.value))
            goalC.reinitialize()
            nbGoal.config(text=" | Goals: "+str(goalC.value))
            lvl.config(text=" | Current level: "+str(lvlC.value), bg="darkgray")
            print("New moves",muvC.value, "New pushes",pushC.value, "New level",lvlC.value)
            print("New countX: ", lm.countX())
            print("New goals: ", goalC.value)
            for i in l:
                print(i)
            for i in lm:
                print(i)
            can.delete("all")
            for i in r:
                for j in r:
                    time.sleep(.005)
                    can.create_rectangle(j*n, i*n, j*n+n, i*n+n, fill=fillSquare(i,j, l), outline="darkslategray")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent from changing"? Things don't change by themselves, something must be modifying it. The code you've posted isn't enough to figure out what's happening or what you want; please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: There is indeed a very simple way to "prevent (your) list class from changing" : don't change it.  If this doesn't answer your question, you may want to re-word your question with more specific details and use cases.

Comment: Also: inheritance (implementation inheritance - but that's the only reason to use inheritance in Python) is mostly a very crippled form of composition/delegation. I strongly suggest you rewrite your `Maps` class using composition/delegation instead. That's a bit more work at first but it gives you full control over the implementation AND more flexibility.

Comment: Note that `Maps() + []` will return `[]`. So to have a proper subclass you'll have to reimplement a lot of methods.

Comment: Well, I am working on a game where I make events and they modify the `l` list. I only want that list to respond to the events. but even though I do not give the instruction to change `lm` it does change too. I would join my whole code, but it'd take pages. ^^>

Comment: @Chihab as tzaman mentioned, "things don't change by themselved", and what you describe here is symptomatic of a shared reference to a mutable container. You **really* have to come with a minimal, complete, verifiable code snippet reproducing this behaviour. Chances are you'll find the problem by yourself during the process FWIW.

Comment: sure! I will join the part of the code that does the change. and sorry if I don't explain that well, I've only started learning OOP a couple days ago. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to define such things using different classes. It's not a good idea having instances of the same class mutable and immutable at the same time.

So I suggest you to define all your methods in MixinClass and then make 2 classes, one is subclass of `list`(mutable) another is subclass of `tuple`(immutable)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I wouldn't inherit from either one or the other - composition/delegation has worked better for me 99.9 times out of 100 over the past 17 years.

Comment: I will read more documentation on composition and delegation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that

```
class BaseMaps(list):

def createInitial(self, lvlC):
    #self.extend(mapDico[lvlC.value])

#get (i,j) coords of "i" in l
def findI(self):
    for ordinate, abscissa in enumerate(self):
        try:
            return (ordinate, abscissa.index("i"))
        except:
            pass

#get number of "x" in lm
def countX(self):
    nbX=0
    for rows in range(len(self)):
        for elements in range(len(self)):
            if self[rows][elements]=="x":
                nbX+=1
    return nbX

#load next map
def nextLevel(self, nxtL):
    del self[:]
    self.extend(mapDico[nxtL])



class Maps(BaseMaps):

    pass


class ReadOnlyMaps(BaseMaps):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self._list = other

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._list)

    def __slice__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._list.__slice__(*args, **kw)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._list)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def NotImplemented(self, *args, **kw):
        raise ValueError("Read Only list proxy")

    append = pop = __setitem__ = __setslice__ = __delitem__ = NotImplemented
```

Comment: `NotImplemented` is the name of a builtin object, so I wouldn't recommend using that name for another purpose (even if it is contained within a class namespace). Also, if you're overriding all the list interface methods, there's no reason to be inheriting from `list`.

Comment: I thought that because I'm working with lists. But I will read more about this right away and see what I can change to make it better.